# PHP looping over a list and store in a MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am a self taught CS student and I am currently working on a job listing website. I am now working on the back-end page where the business owner will be able to see, add or remove a job. [this is how the back end looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02yzL.png).

Each jobs has 9 attributes allocated between three different tables `jobs, keywords, requirements` :

- Job-ID (jobs table - primary key)
- Title (jobs table)
- Type (jobs table)
- Location (jobs table)
- Salary (jobs table)
- Description (jobs table)
- Date (jobs table)
- Keyword (keywords table since each jobs can have multiple keywords)
- Requirement (requirements table since each jobs can have multiple requirements)

Right now, I am able to submit a new job and store all the attributes for the jobs table but I have problems with the other two tables.

My issue is unlike the `jobs` table, the user can add multiple keywords. So I have implemented a JavaScript Function in `add-jobs.js` to create a new `innerHTLM ul .list-keywords` whenever the user will submit. What I need to do, is to loop over the `.list-keywords`  and take the `NodeValue` of each `li` item. Then, I will have create an equal number of `rows` in my database as there is`li`.

It was much more easier for the jobs table since I just had to do `$attribute = $_POST["attribute_name"]` but with a list I have no idea how to do it

[keywords table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz18S.png)

**Add-jobs.js**

```
const keywords = document.querySelector(".keywords");
const addKeyword = document.querySelector(".add-keyword");
const listKeywords = document.querySelector(".list-keywords");

 const generateTemplate = (word, location) => {
     const html = `
        <li><span>${word}</span>
        <i class="far fa-times-circle delete"></i>
        </li> `;

     location.innerHTML += html;
 };


addKeyword.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const word = keywords.value.trim();
    console.log(word);
    keywords.value = "";
    generateTemplate(word, listKeywords);
});


listKeywords.addEventListener("click", e =>{
    if(e.target.classList.contains("delete")){
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
    };

});
```

**Add-jobs.php**

```
</p>
    <div class="add">
        <label for="keywords">Keywords : </label>     
        <input type="text" class="keywords" name="keywords" value=""/>   
        <button class="add-keyword">Add</button>               
    </div>
        <ul class="list-keywords">
        </ul>
<p>
```

**Add-databse.php**

```
<?php
    require("config/db.php");
    require("add-jobs.php");


    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","benoit");



    $title = $_POST["position"];
    $type = $_POST["job-type"];
    $location = $_POST["location"];
    $salary = $_POST["salary"];
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $date = $publisheddate;


    mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO jobs (`title`, `type`, `location`, `salary`, `description`, `date`)
VALUES ('$title', '$type', '$location', '$salary', '$description', CURDATE())") 
or die(mysqli_error($link));


?>
```

Comment: You are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You need to use prepared statements, rather than concatenating variables into your query. (Note that simply escaping your variables—which you are not currently doing—is not enough.) See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).

Comment: Thank you Ed, I saw it already but I am thinking to protect my code once I will understand how can I add the keywords in the DB

Comment: Famous last words. And see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Have you made any attempt yet to do the looping you describe? You have the right idea; have you started implementing the loop? (And, as @Strawberry hinted, it's a much better idea and far easier to write secure code *first* than to try to make insecure code safe later.)

Comment: No I haven't started the loop because I has not sure if I has to do the loop with php or it will be with JS. I will prevent the SQL injections right now then, probably a better idea.

Comment: You may want to look up what the backtick operator does.

Answer (score 0):

Change your keyword inputs to

```html
<input type="text" class="keywords" name="keywords[]" value=""/>
```

(Notice the `[]` after the `name` attribute)

PHP will put all added keywords as an array into `$_POST['keywords']`. Now you can loop through the array and insert each keyword one by one:

```php
$jobId = ... // <- get last insert id here for job id
foreach($_POST['keywords'] as $keyword) {
   // insert each $keyword and $jobId relation into db separately
}
```

And of course you should use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/4946451) to insert your data safely into your database (as the commenters already noted, use them right from the beginning, don't add them *later*, as this mostly does not happen).

Comment: Thank you Arkuuu, I have a question. I do not really why the jobID is 0 by default. job_id is actually the primary key of the jobs table and job_id is also in the keywords table as a foreign key.

Comment: Sorry, that was misleading. It's not 0 by default, I was just unsure how to write that it is infact the last insert id (and thus primary key) ob jobs table.

Comment: Thanks and also seems the name="keywords[]" is not working because the size is always 0. I added a class "indivKeywords" to the innerHTML on the JavaScript when I am creating the <li> and I am able to get the size of the list with indivKeywords.lenght

Comment: However, it's on the JS file so I can't use POST for that, I am a bit confused